# Quartz job doesn't restart after instance fail

Tags: quartz-scheduler, restart, jobs

I have QUARTZ 1.8.5 running in a clustered environment (2 nodes, persistence, clustered , JobStoreCMT). 
Now I schedule several jobs to run everyday at a specific hour.
I set REQUEST RECOVERY to true for every of these jobs (jobDetail.setRequestsRecovery(true).
I see that the flag is set to 1 into QRTZ_JOB_DETAILS table.
What I want is that a node fails (Jboss server is restarted for example) then the other alive node to restart the failed job. But this doesn't happens.

What I'm doing wrong/ not doing ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to update to the latest Quartz? There is a version `2.1.6` out already.

Otherwise, what you're doing seems to be right.

Comment: It was right, I don't know why didn't work at the beginning :)

Comment: Perhaps, it was a bug in Quartz 1.8.5, if you dig the archives probably you find notices about it. If you have problems, it's always worth to check id there are more recent versions or not.